# How to recreate the += operator without using it

Tags: javascript

uh hi guys so im having a problem that i don't know how to avoid i'm making a dictionary and i know the cause of the problem but don't really know how to fix it

javascript:

```
show = function(i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < dictionary[i].content_titles.length; j++) {
        console.log('hi')
        document.getElementById('topic_div').innerHTML +=
`<h3>${dictionary[i].content_titles[j]}</h3>`;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="topic" id="topic_div">
  <h3 id="topic_text"></h3>
  <p id="content"></p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

basically whats happening is since im using the += operator whenever the function activates it runs the for loop all over again, i thought of using a cache but i need the html h3, p, and hr to stay bc that's going to hold the name and the starting content which is why i can't delete the html and run it in the for loop with the rest of the titles
so how do I fix my problem while keeping the same layout intact

Comment: Not sure what you're asking entirely, can you clear the inner HTML before the loop?

Comment: No, I want to keep the html intact while not breaking the code.

Comment: have you tried adding another div/span below `<hr>`  and add id to it then put all your new values in there?

Comment: @timnaire no, I haven't actually I may try that right now. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @JaromandaX the first time it should have the original html and the html I added with javascript 
The second time it shouldn't change if i is the same, but if i is different the html I added should change

Comment: "while not breaking the code" is ambiguous. What is your expected input and output? You're adding to the innerHTML but no idea what you're after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another span to contain your `content_titles`

```
<div class="topic" id="topic_div">
  <h3 id="topic_text"></h3>
  <p id="content"></p>
  <hr>
  <span id="content_titles"></span>
</div>
```

```
show = function(i) {
    document.getElementById('content_titles').innerHTML = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < dictionary[i].content_titles.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById('content_titles').innerHTML +=
        `<h3>${dictionary[i].content_titles[j]}</h3>`;
    }
}
```

not sure if this is what you wanted, but try it.